# convert json to form builder using angular2+

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

i have thie json file for example:

```
{
  "properties": [
    {
      "id": "title",
      "label": "Title",
      "tooltip": "Title",
      "type": "MultiChoice",
      "viewMode": "edit",
      "required": true,
      "choices": [
        {
          "text": "Mr",
          "value": "Mr"
        },
        {
          "text": "Mrs",
          "value": "Mrs"
        },
        {
          "text": "Miss",
          "value": "Miss"
        }
      ],
      "value": null
    },
    {
      "id": "firstName",
      "label": "First Name",
      "tooltip": "First Name",
      "type": "Text",
      "length": 128,
      "required": true,
      "viewMode": "edit",
      "value": null
    },

  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "id": "save",
      "label": "Save"
    },
    {
      "id": "cancel",
      "label": "Cancel"
    }
  ]
}
```

i need to convert this json file to form in angular2 : it will look like :

```
<form>
   <input type="checkbox"  name="Mr" value="Mr"> Mr<br>
   <input type="checkbox"  name="Mrs" value="Mr"> Mrs<br>
   <input type="checkbox"  name="Mr" value="Miss> Miss<br>
   FirstName: 
   <input type="text">
   <input type="button" >save <br>
   <input type="button" >cancel<br>
</form>
```

and then when the user edit this form  i need to update the values in the json file , anyone have any idea how to start at least to solve this problem?
using angular2+ and html5

Comment: which type of angular form are you using?

Comment: anyone no problem

Comment: so you want to generate a form out of that json?

Comment: you should go with ReactiveForm approach of angular

Comment: @messerbill yes

Comment: @JoeSleiman yes, ReactiveForms seems to be what you are searching for: https://stackblitz.com/angular/nqmekpjonyb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero-detail%2Fhero-detail.component.ts - I'd never used it so i could only provide a solution using `@ViewChild` but that reactive forms examples looks much better